# Choosing Encryption Strategies for Secure Long-Term Storage of Sensitive Data

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management, disk-encryption, file-encryption

When considering external drives for secure long-term storage of sensitive data, what are the pros and cons of using the same password for encrypting all files versus using random passwords for each file (or junk of files), and how does this compare to disk-level encryption in terms of security and usability?

My priorities are security, long-term accessibility, non-dependency on a specific machine or OS, and lastly usability (keep it simple to avoid error).

How risky is the use of a single key (as in full disk encryption, or with a single password) versus using many random keys (with the downside of having to manage these passwords anyway)? Please assume some adversary has physical access to the external drive.

Bonus question: How would your answer change if storage was on the cloud instead of an external drive

Comment: A huge part of this will depend on how you're managing those passwords. Having 50 different passwords doesn't really help much if you keep them all in the same place.

Comment: The passwords are kept separate from the external drive (i.e. from data they encrypt)  inside some password management system or software. But they would indeed be in one place, locked with a single password (and potentially MFA).

Comment: You keep only one strong password to derive a master key that will generate sub-keys per file or per directory. Also, derive a metadata key from master key to encrypt file metadata.